# Convert UTF-8 character encoded UInt32 bytes to UInt32 directly in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, byte

I've byte array below

```
let byteArray: [UInt8] = [53, 51, 57, 52] //5394
```

Which is 4 bytes of UInt32 value encoded as UTF-8 Character. I can get UInt32 value by using string literal

```
let byteArray: [UInt8] = [53, 51, 57, 52]
let string = String(bytes: byteArray, encoding: .utf8)!
print("\(string)")
let intValue = UInt32(string)!
```

I am doing this conversion very frequently with large data set in my program. So Instead of doing this kinda conversion and implicitily unwraping optionals I wonder is there any way to initialize UInt32 directly using the UTF-8 chars? Thanking you!

Comment: So basically you have a string expression of an UInt32 and you want to convert the string back into a UInt32, right? If so, you first need to decode the string (just like you did) and init the UInt32. You would safe you some time by using swifts JSONDecoder and just pass in your array of bytes as Data.

Comment: I have reopened the question because the linked duplicate was about concatenating four bytes tougher not a `UInt32`. This is about converting ASCII text (or UTF-8 text) into an `Int`. Different problem.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the array contains only character codes for decimal digits, i.e. only values in the range 48...57 ?

Comment: you have not explained your problem clearly. From your sample data and your code it looks like your array of `UInt8`s contains the character codes for decimal digits, and you want to convert that to a string and then evaluate the numeric value contained in that string. Is that correct?

Comment: @MartinR, Yes It is guaranted that the array contains number digits and It won't exceed above UInt32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach in general. In fact, if your bytes represent the UTF-8 representation of a number but you re not 100% certain that is the case, doing what you do and unwrapping safely is the easiest way to handle malformed numbers.

If, however, you know you will always have an array of four ASCII digits, you can do the conversion directly. As long as it is base 10, you can obtain each digit simply by subtracting 48 from the ASCII, 48 being the ASCII representation of zero.

```
var result: UInt32 = 0

for ascii in byteArray
{
    result = result * 10 + UInt32(ascii) - 48
}
print(result) // 5394
```

There are a couple of pitfalls in the above code, if the input is not what you expect. If the array is more than about nine digits, the code will crash when `result` overflows. If the array contains bytes other than ASCII digits, you will get a nonsense result.

Comment: Or as a one-liner with reduce: `byteArray.reduce(0) { 10 * $0 + UInt32($1) - 48 }`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't go through for loop and muls. instead I've just take `48` only. i.e., `UInt32(byteArray.map({"\($0 - 48)"}).joined())!`

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy's answer is a good start but I am leery of code that blindly parses unverified input and crashes if the input is badly formatted.

Starting with Jeremy's answer, I'd create a throwing function:

```
enum ConverionError: Error {
    case wrongLength(byteArray: [UInt8], length: Int)
    case invalidChar(byteArray: [UInt8], index: Int)
}


func byteArrayToInt(_ byteArray: [UInt8]) throws -> UInt32 {
    var result: UInt32 = 0

    guard byteArray.count == 4 else { throw ConverionError.wrongLength(byteArray: byteArray, length:byteArray.count) }
    for (index, ascii) in byteArray.enumerated()
    {
        guard ascii >= 48 && ascii <= 57 else { throw ConverionError.invalidChar(byteArray: byteArray, index: index) }
        result = result * 10 + UInt32(ascii) - 48
    }
    return result
}
```

Demo code using that function:

```
do {
    let byteArrays: [[UInt8]] = [
        [49, 48, 48, 48],
        [49, 50, 51, 52],
        [49, 48, 48, 48, 48],
        [49, 48, 48, 48, 32],
    ]
    for aByteArray in byteArrays {
        let value = try byteArrayToInt(aByteArray)
        print("Byte array \(aByteArray) = \(value)")

    }
} catch {
    switch error as! ConverionError {
    case .wrongLength(let byteArray, let length):
        print("ByteArray \(byteArray) wrong length. Should be 4 chars. Found \(length) chars instead")
    case .invalidChar(let byteArray, let index):
        print("ByteArray \(byteArray) contains invalid char at index \(index)")
    }
    print("Error converting ")
}
```

And the output of that test code looks like this:

> Byte array [49, 48, 48, 48] = 1000 
> Byte array [49, 50, 51, 52] = 1234 
> ByteArray [49, 48, 48, 48, 48] wrong length. Should be 4 chars. Found 5 chars instead 
> Error converting